# Return statement in an infinite loop

Tags: c, return, infinite-loop, mplab

Where does this return statement return to if it is inside this infinite while(1) loop? More importantly, I had no idea that a while(1) loop could be broken???

```
void __attribute__((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _T3Interrupt(void)
{
int count;

    IFS0bits.T3IF = 0;          // clear Tmr3 interrupt flag

    StopMotor();
    IEC0bits.ADIE = 0;          // disable ADC interrupt
    IEC0bits.CNIE = 0;          // disable CN interrupt
    IEC0bits.T3IE = 0;          // disable Tmr3 interrupt

    T3CONbits.TON = 1;          // restart tmr3
    count = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        if (IFS0bits.T3IF)
        {
            IFS0bits.T3IF = 0;  // clear flag
            if (count++ >= RESTART_COUNT)
            {
                IEC0bits.ADIE = 1;          // enable ADC interrupt
                IEC0bits.CNIE = 1;          // enable CN interrupt
                T3CONbits.TON = 0;          // stop tmr3
                IEC0bits.T3IE = 1;          // enable Tmr3 interrupt
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: `break;` will also exit a while(1) loop.

Comment: There are (at least) three ways to exit a loop: `break;`, `return;`, and `goto`

Comment: ...`throw` is aonther

Comment: `longjmp()` and `exit()` also come to mind.

Comment: @Simon isn't `throw` a c++ construct?

Comment: I guess we dispelled the idea that a while(1) loop in no exitable ;)

Comment: @dlcto - oh la la.  I thought I was in Android land ;)  Yep, not in C. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All return statements will return to wherever the function was called from, regardless of where they are located within the function.

For instance, if I wrote:

```
int main()
{
    _iT3Interrupt();

}
```

Then the return statement in `_iT3Interrupt` will revert control flow back to `main`.

Also, *any* loop can be exited (even if the condition is `1`, `true`, or some equivalent) with any of the following constructs:

```
break; //exits the loop

return; //exits the function, thus ending the loop

goto <label-outside-loop>; //self-explanatory

exit(); abort(); //exits the program. Bit of a stretch to say that this ends the loop...
```

And in C++, `throw`, which will unwind the stack until it reaches a corresponding catch, thus exiting the function. The C `setjmp` and `longjmp` functions may also be applicable here, but I don't know enough C to be certain of their usage.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to get out of a loop with `return` `break` `goto`

with your snippet if `IFS0bits.T3IF != 0` then it will eventually break out of the loop when `count >= RESET_COUNT`.  After that it will return to where the function was called from.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, while(1) is more like while(true). Therefore, it keeps on looping until it encounters a break.

Answer (score 0):

When a function is called the address the function (or ISR) is called from is put on the top of the stack.
The execution of `return` will end the function (or ISR). The programm counter (PC) is updated with this address, so the program flow could continue with the statement following the calling address.